# Sound effects on button click

Tags: android

Is there any easy way to put sound effects within an onClick method when the user clicks the sound effect will make a sound. :)

I have looked into this but cannot find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a SoundPool, look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Load the sounds you need into your SoundPool and then use the play() method.

Comment: Thanks, that provides great theory on how to incorporate sound. I think this is also a little more practical: http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-2,695.html    Thanks for your help